# Task 'nativeImage' not found in project ':dolphin-music:dolphin-music-service'

Tags: java, gradle

I want to build my spring boot project as a native app that could run with GraalVM, now I am using this command :

```
./gradlew clean :dolphin-music:dolphin-music-service:nativeImage -x test
```

but the result tell me that:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'nativeImage' not found in project ':dolphin-music:dolphin-music-service'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 428ms
```

this is my build.gradle config:

```
project(":dolphin-music") {
    dependencies {
    }
}

project(":dolphin-music:dolphin-music-api") {
    jar {
        enabled = true
    }

    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }

    dependencies {
    }
}

project(":dolphin-music:dolphin-music-service") {
    archivesBaseName = "dolphin-music-service"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    bootJar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Start-Class': 'com.dolphin.soa.music.AppStarter'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":dolphin-music:dolphin-music-api")
    }

    nativeImage {
        mainClassName              = 'com.dolphin.soa.music.AppStarter'
        traceClassInitialization   = true
        reportExceptionStackTraces = true
        removeUnusedAutoConfig     = true
        removeYamlSupport          = true
        removeSpelSupport          = true
        removeJmxSupport           = true
        maxHeapSize                = '4G'
    }

}
```

why tell me task not found even that I have already defined the `nativeImage` task.what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I hope graalvm is install , if not please follow the below the document
https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/ along with [instructions](https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/docs/getting-started/linux/) for exporting the variables

```
gu install native-image

./gradlew nativeCompile
```

This worked for me :)

Comment: ./build/native/nativeCompile/{project/application-name} for running